# Compile to number of pages

Tags: layout

Is it possible to make LaTeX format the document in such a way that it fills exactly a number of pages? For example, to give LaTeX enough text to fill roughly two pages make make LaTeX take care of the margins, if necessary parskip… so the two pages are exactly filled? If not, I would do this by trial and error, which seems a bit against LaTeX-philosophy.

Comment: Do you want to fill n pages with any text or do you have a text, that should fill n pages?

Comment: I want to fill them with text I already have. It is an assignment that must be exactly two pages. My text is roughly 2 pages, so I would like to use the lay-out to make it exactly two pages.

Comment: Which parameters could be changed to do the job? Font size, page margin, baseline skip … And no care for typography? IMHO this would not be the LaTeX philosophy.

Comment: I guess the margin but I don't know exactly. The needed adjustments aren't very big. I need maximum 2-3 lines of text extra so I guess the impact on typography would be minimal (the font size is really small)

Comment: Adjusting the margins is not going to help, even the slightest adjustment is too big to keep the text on 2 pages.

Comment: If the the text is just 2 lines too short to fill the second page, you could place `\vfill` in between paragraphs. This will stretch their distance a bit.

Comment: Try `\looseness=1` at some paragraphs. TeX will try to increase the paragraph's length by 1 line with this value. Longer paragraphs or paragraphs with almost full last line would be good candidates.

Comment: I have removed the [geometry] tag, as that applies explicitly to the `geometry` package.  Replaced by [layout].